# Create a column in excel and add the contents of other columns to it

Tags: excel

[its an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YetI1.jpg) I have a file in Excel that contains 20 columns with textual content and these contents are regularly either edited or added to each column.
I want to create a new column that contains the content of all the other columns. For example, if the previous 20 columns have 5 text cells each, this new column contains 100 text cells based on the previous columns and is waiting to be added or edited in the previous columns.

Comment: There is no obvious way to handle the insertion of new rows to keep the single column in sync with the 20 other columns. Most importantly, what are you trying to achieve? The response to this question might be the key to providing a solution. Otherwise, a handcrafted macro will be necessary to get what you want. That's not ideal.

Comment: What does "waiting to added or edited" mean?

Comment: i mean taht   content of each 20 column maybe edited  remove  or added ...  so i want to column 21  update too.

Comment: In your example you show only two columns with results in column C.  If the single column with the results can move from other than column `U` (the 21st colunmn), you will need to develop a VBA or Power Query solution, to be refreshed whenever you add a column.  If the results will always be in column U, then what happened when you tried  the answer provided below?

Comment: exactly ... columns maybe added more than 20  or deleted .. but i want to entire of contents of column  1 to N  shown in on column  for example  u.  column u is attach to other columns and updatable with other columns .

Comment: Will the results always be in column U?

Comment: I think that the new column should be in a separate sheet, isn't it?

Comment: You are the one with the problem. How should I know where the new column is going? But if it's always going to be in the same place, then what is the problem with the answer provided below?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand exactly what you're doing, but if you put this function in cell `U1` it will spill down all values in the prior 20 columns.

```
=FILTERXML("<r><c>"&TEXTJOIN("</c><c>",TRUE,A:T)&"</c></r>","//c")
```

This won't work on mac or web instances of excel.

If you have the latest Excel formulas that recently came out in 2022, then you could also use this formula which is available for Excel on Web.

```
=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("????",TRUE,A:T),,"????")
```

Comment: Column a and column b currently have 3 filled cells, whose content should be in column c. But in the future, another content may be added to columns a and b, or the current content may change, which should also change column c.

Comment: Yes that's what it does.

Answer (score 0):

To return the results as a stacked column of your multiple columns, if you have Excel 365, you can try the following formula, placed outside of your data range

```
=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,BYCOL(Sheet3!$A:$T, LAMBDA(arr, TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,arr)))),,";")
```

Replace `A:T` with whatvever range includes all of your data (there can be blank rows and/or blank columns).

***Input Data on Sheet3***
[image]

***Formula on Sheet3***
[image]

Comment: tnx ... 
This function is very interesting, but unfortunately I have Excel 2022 and I don't have these functions like textsplit or tocol.

Comment: @mohsen I wasn't aware there was an Excel 2022. I thought the most recent non-365 version was 2021.  It may be then that the simplest thing for you to get your desired output from your input would be to write a VBA routine.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and answer

Comment: And by the way, I apologize for the typo in the office version that I wrote. It is 2021.

Comment: And that you think the VBA code is ready for this project.